# the file directories on Jelly Bean 4.2

Tags: android, file, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a problem of the file directories on Jelly Bean 4.2. I know with later versions to access the files you had to use the directory / sdcard /

but Jelly Bean 4.2  it does not work.

That is what can help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You may try with that function, should work for every device:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```